# libtool is installed but build cannot find it

Tags: macos, libtool-xcode

I'm trying to build OpenSSL on macOS for iOS 11. The make command fails with "libtool not found error".

I've checked the output of which command for libtool and result is as expected:

```
[Amy-MacBook-Pro-3:openssl-fips-ecp-2.0.12 $ which libtool
/usr/bin/libtool
```

PATH variable shows /usr/bin listed:

```
[Amy-MacBook-Pro-3:openssl-fips-ecp-2.0.12 $ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

This is the error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'libtool'
make[2]: *** [../libcrypto.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [build_fips] Error 1
```

I listed the version of libtool below:

```
[Amy-MacBook-Pro-3:openssl-fips-ecp-2.0.12 $ libtool --version
libtool (GNU libtool) 2.4.4
Written by Gordon Matzigkeit, 1996

Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by doing the following:

```
export PATH="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin":$PATH
```